# A better 8x8 bytes matrix transpose with SSE?

Tags: c, matrix, optimization, sse, simd

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518670/6570821) that explains how to transpose an 8x8 bytes matrix with 24 operations, and a few scrolls later there's [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4951060/6570821) that implements the transpose. However, this method does not exploit the fact that we can *block* the 8x8 transpose into four 4x4 transposes, and each one can be done in one shuffle instruction only ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24819208/6570821) is the reference). So I came out with this solution:

```
__m128i transpose4x4mask = _mm_set_epi8(15, 11, 7, 3, 14, 10, 6, 2, 13,  9, 5, 1, 12,  8, 4, 0);
__m128i shuffle8x8Mask = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 4,  5, 6, 7, 12,  13, 14, 15);

void TransposeBlock8x8(uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dst, int srcStride, int dstStride) {
    __m128i load0 = _mm_set_epi64x(*(uint64_t*)(src + 1 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 0 * srcStride));
    __m128i load1 = _mm_set_epi64x(*(uint64_t*)(src + 3 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 2 * srcStride));
    __m128i load2 = _mm_set_epi64x(*(uint64_t*)(src + 5 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 4 * srcStride));
    __m128i load3 = _mm_set_epi64x(*(uint64_t*)(src + 7 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 6 * srcStride));

    __m128i shuffle0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(load0, shuffle8x8Mask);
    __m128i shuffle1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(load1, shuffle8x8Mask);
    __m128i shuffle2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(load2, shuffle8x8Mask);
    __m128i shuffle3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(load3, shuffle8x8Mask);

    __m128i block0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(shuffle0, shuffle1);
    __m128i block1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(shuffle0, shuffle1);
    __m128i block2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(shuffle2, shuffle3);
    __m128i block3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(shuffle2, shuffle3);

    __m128i transposed0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(block0, transpose4x4mask);   
    __m128i transposed1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(block1, transpose4x4mask);   
    __m128i transposed2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(block2, transpose4x4mask);   
    __m128i transposed3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(block3, transpose4x4mask);   

    __m128i store0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(transposed0, transposed2);
    __m128i store1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(transposed0, transposed2);
    __m128i store2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(transposed1, transposed3);
    __m128i store3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(transposed1, transposed3);

    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 0 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store0, 0);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 1 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store0, 1);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 2 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store1, 0);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 3 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store1, 1);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 4 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store2, 0);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 5 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store2, 1);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 6 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store3, 0);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 7 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store3, 1);
}
```

Excluding load/store operations this procedure consists of only 16 instructions instead of 24.

What am I missing?

Comment: You missed 4 128-bit operations to load vectors and 4 128-bit operations to store vectors.

Comment: __m128i load0 = _mm_set_epi64x(*(uint64_t*)(src + 1 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 0 * srcStride)); it is equal to __m128i load0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(src + 0 * srcStride));

Comment: *((uint64_t*)(dst + 0 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store0, 0);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 1 * dstStride)) = _mm_extract_epi64(store0, 1); is equal to _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(src + 0 * srcStride), store0);

Comment: @ErmIg: Load/Store should be excluded from the ops. The post with 24 ops I linked do not take them into account. You have to load data anyway, no?

Comment: @ErmIg: They are only equivalent only if `srcStride` is `8` and `dstStride` is `8`, that is if src and dst are both matrices of 8x8 bytes each. They are different otherwise, eg matrices of 128x128 bytes, but I'm actually "zooming-in" into an 8x8 block only, in that case `scrStride` and `dstStride` would be both `128`.

Comment: You have used sleight of hand by using `_mm_set_epi64x`. This is not a single instruction. It uses multiple instructions to perform some shuffling so it's not just a simple load.   It can be implemented as some combination of `_mm_loadl_epi64` and `_mm_insert_epi64` https://godbolt.org/g/xswKoD. Also, normally you would use 4 stores but you use 8 extracts. So the four inserts and four extra extracts make up for the 8 missing instructions I think.

Comment: @Zboson:I see I load/store in *particular* way, but you still need to load/store anyway.It seems that other links don't take load/store into account.The thing is that if matrices row bytes are consecutive in memory we can perform 4 load/stores directly,but if they are not (eg zooming-in larger matrices) you can't perform "simple" loads/stores, hence the crafted code.I see the `_mm_set_epi64x` actually counts for 1x`movq`, 1x`pinsrq` + 1x `LEA` to address the correct byte.Can we load in a better way?If compiled with `AVX` GCC use some extra XMM registers and the compiled is a bit shorter.

Comment: Have you considered packing the 8x8 blocks so that you can access them without strides? I mean a 64 element array where each element a one of the 8x8 byte matrices (so really the array is 8x8*64=4096 bytes)? That's the kind of thing I do with matrix multiplication. Maybe you should describe exactly what you're doing. There is possibly more more efficient SIMD method than what you are doing now using `srcStride` and `dstStride`.

Comment: @Zboson : For an 8x8 (byte, short, float, double etc.) matrix transpose you need 24 instructions, if the instructions have 
an output of 8 elements per instruction. See also your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29587984/2439725). 
With the byte matrix transpose, the SSE instructions have an output of 16 bytes, or two rows, per instruction.
So, if we are lucky we can reduce the number of instructions by a factor of two, if the shuffle instructions are 
flexible enough. Indeed we only need 12 instructions, see my answer below.

Comment: @Zboson:Actually my matrices are Nx32, N rows x 32 cols bytes. Here 32 is fixed and won't change while 1 <= N <= 128. I need to transpose them back and forth, and being N variable leads to a variable strides (both in and out). The main goal is to read the matrices by column major for some processing, while leaving them normally in row major for other processing. I'm also trying to figure out how to do the best depending on N and the transposition type (Nx32 with one procedure, 32xN with another).

Comment: @xmas79 : An 8x8 transpose is also possible with 8 shuffles and 8 blends. In my experiments this is about 18% faster than the solution with 12 shuffles, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the loads, stores and `pinsrq`-s to read from and write to memory, with possibly a stride not equal to 8 bytes,
you can do the transpose with only 12 instructions (this code can easily be used in combination with Z boson's test code):

```
void tran8x8b_SSE_v2(char *A, char *B) {
  __m128i pshufbcnst = _mm_set_epi8(15,11,7,3, 14,10,6,2, 13,9,5,1, 12,8,4,0);

  __m128i B0, B1, B2, B3, T0, T1, T2, T3;
  B0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[ 0]);
  B1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[16]);
  B2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[32]);
  B3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[48]);


  T0 = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(B0),_mm_castsi128_ps(B1),0b10001000));
  T1 = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(B2),_mm_castsi128_ps(B3),0b10001000));
  T2 = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(B0),_mm_castsi128_ps(B1),0b11011101));
  T3 = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(B2),_mm_castsi128_ps(B3),0b11011101));

  B0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T0,pshufbcnst);
  B1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T1,pshufbcnst);
  B2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T2,pshufbcnst);
  B3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T3,pshufbcnst);

  T0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(B0,B1);
  T1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(B0,B1);
  T2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(B2,B3);
  T3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(B2,B3);

  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[ 0], T0);
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[16], T1);
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[32], T2);
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[48], T3);
}
```

Here we use the 32 bit floating point shuffle which is more flexible than the `epi32` shuffle.
The casts do not generate extra instructions (code generated with gcc 5.4):

```
tran8x8b_SSE_v2:
.LFB4885:
    .cfi_startproc
    vmovdqu 48(%rdi), %xmm5
    vmovdqu 32(%rdi), %xmm2
    vmovdqu 16(%rdi), %xmm0
    vmovdqu (%rdi), %xmm1
    vshufps $136, %xmm5, %xmm2, %xmm4
    vshufps $221, %xmm5, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmovdqa .LC6(%rip), %xmm5
    vshufps $136, %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm3
    vshufps $221, %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm1
    vpshufb %xmm5, %xmm3, %xmm3
    vpshufb %xmm5, %xmm1, %xmm0
    vpshufb %xmm5, %xmm4, %xmm4
    vpshufb %xmm5, %xmm2, %xmm1
    vpunpckldq  %xmm4, %xmm3, %xmm5
    vpunpckldq  %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm2
    vpunpckhdq  %xmm4, %xmm3, %xmm3
    vpunpckhdq  %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmovups %xmm5, (%rsi)
    vmovups %xmm3, 16(%rsi)
    vmovups %xmm2, 32(%rsi)
    vmovups %xmm0, 48(%rsi)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

On some, but not all, older cpus there might be a small bypass delay (between 0 and 2 cycles) for moving data between the
integer and the floating point units. This increases the latency of the function, but it does not necessarily affect the
throughput of the code.

A simple latency test with 1e9 tranpositions:

```
  for (int i=0;i<500000000;i++){
     tran8x8b_SSE(A,C);
     tran8x8b_SSE(C,A);
  }
  print8x8b(A);
```

This takes about 5.5 seconds (19.7e9 cycles) with tran8x8b_SSE and 4.5 seconds (16.0e9 cycles) with tran8x8b_SSE_v2 (Intel core i5-6500). Note that
the load and stores were not eliminated by the compiler, although the functions were inlined in the for loop.

**Update: AVX2-128 / SSE 4.1 solution with blends.**

The 'shuffles' (unpack, shuffle) are handled by port 5, with 1 instruction per cpu cycle on modern cpus.
Sometimes it pays off to replace one 'shuffle' with two blends. On Skylake the 32 bit blend instructions can run on either port 0, 1 or 5.

Unfortunately, `_mm_blend_epi32` is only AVX2-128. An efficient SSE 4.1 alternative is `_mm_blend_ps` in combination 
with a few casts (which are usually free). The 12 'shuffles' are replaced by
8 shuffles in combination with 8 blends.

The simple latency test now runs in about 3.6 seconds (13e9 cpu cycles), which is 18 % faster than the results with `tran8x8b_SSE_v2`.

Code:

```
/* AVX2-128 version, sse 4.1 version see ---------------->       SSE 4.1 version of tran8x8b_AVX2_128()                                                              */
void tran8x8b_AVX2_128(char *A, char *B) {                   /*  void tran8x8b_SSE4_1(char *A, char *B) {                                                            */                                    
  __m128i pshufbcnst_0 = _mm_set_epi8(15, 7,11, 3,  
               13, 5, 9, 1,  14, 6,10, 2,  12, 4, 8, 0);     /*    __m128i pshufbcnst_0 = _mm_set_epi8(15, 7,11, 3,  13, 5, 9, 1,  14, 6,10, 2,  12, 4, 8, 0);       */                                    
  __m128i pshufbcnst_1 = _mm_set_epi8(13, 5, 9, 1,  
               15, 7,11, 3,  12, 4, 8, 0,  14, 6,10, 2);     /*    __m128i pshufbcnst_1 = _mm_set_epi8(13, 5, 9, 1,  15, 7,11, 3,  12, 4, 8, 0,  14, 6,10, 2);       */                                    
  __m128i pshufbcnst_2 = _mm_set_epi8(11, 3,15, 7,  
                9, 1,13, 5,  10, 2,14, 6,   8, 0,12, 4);     /*    __m128i pshufbcnst_2 = _mm_set_epi8(11, 3,15, 7,   9, 1,13, 5,  10, 2,14, 6,   8, 0,12, 4);       */                                    
  __m128i pshufbcnst_3 = _mm_set_epi8( 9, 1,13, 5,  
               11, 3,15, 7,   8, 0,12, 4,  10, 2,14, 6);     /*    __m128i pshufbcnst_3 = _mm_set_epi8( 9, 1,13, 5,  11, 3,15, 7,   8, 0,12, 4,  10, 2,14, 6);       */                                    
  __m128i B0, B1, B2, B3, T0, T1, T2, T3;                    /*    __m128 B0, B1, B2, B3, T0, T1, T2, T3;                                                            */                                    
                                                             /*                                                                                                      */                                    
  B0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[ 0]);                    /*    B0 = _mm_loadu_ps((float*)&A[ 0]);                                                                */                                    
  B1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[16]);                    /*    B1 = _mm_loadu_ps((float*)&A[16]);                                                                */                                    
  B2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[32]);                    /*    B2 = _mm_loadu_ps((float*)&A[32]);                                                                */                                    
  B3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[48]);                    /*    B3 = _mm_loadu_ps((float*)&A[48]);                                                                */                                    
                                                             /*                                                                                                      */                                    
  B1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(B1,0b10110001);                     /*    B1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(B1,B1,0b10110001);                                                            */                                    
  B3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(B3,0b10110001);                     /*    B3 = _mm_shuffle_ps(B3,B3,0b10110001);                                                            */                                    
  T0 = _mm_blend_epi32(B0,B1,0b1010);                        /*    T0 = _mm_blend_ps(B0,B1,0b1010);                                                                  */                                    
  T1 = _mm_blend_epi32(B2,B3,0b1010);                        /*    T1 = _mm_blend_ps(B2,B3,0b1010);                                                                  */                                    
  T2 = _mm_blend_epi32(B0,B1,0b0101);                        /*    T2 = _mm_blend_ps(B0,B1,0b0101);                                                                  */                                    
  T3 = _mm_blend_epi32(B2,B3,0b0101);                        /*    T3 = _mm_blend_ps(B2,B3,0b0101);                                                                  */                                    
                                                             /*                                                                                                      */                                    
  B0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T0,pshufbcnst_0);                    /*    B0 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(T0),pshufbcnst_0));                       */                                    
  B1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T1,pshufbcnst_1);                    /*    B1 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(T1),pshufbcnst_1));                       */                                    
  B2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T2,pshufbcnst_2);                    /*    B2 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(T2),pshufbcnst_2));                       */                                    
  B3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T3,pshufbcnst_3);                    /*    B3 = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(T3),pshufbcnst_3));                       */                                    
                                                             /*                                                                                                      */                                    
  T0 = _mm_blend_epi32(B0,B1,0b1010);                        /*    T0 = _mm_blend_ps(B0,B1,0b1010);                                                                  */                                    
  T1 = _mm_blend_epi32(B0,B1,0b0101);                        /*    T1 = _mm_blend_ps(B0,B1,0b0101);                                                                  */                                    
  T2 = _mm_blend_epi32(B2,B3,0b1010);                        /*    T2 = _mm_blend_ps(B2,B3,0b1010);                                                                  */                                    
  T3 = _mm_blend_epi32(B2,B3,0b0101);                        /*    T3 = _mm_blend_ps(B2,B3,0b0101);                                                                  */                                    
  T1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(T1,0b10110001);                     /*    T1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(T1,T1,0b10110001);                                                            */                                    
  T3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(T3,0b10110001);                     /*    T3 = _mm_shuffle_ps(T3,T3,0b10110001);                                                            */                                    
                                                             /*                                                                                                      */                                    
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[ 0], T0);                    /*    _mm_storeu_ps((float*)&B[ 0], T0);                                                                */                                    
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[16], T1);                    /*    _mm_storeu_ps((float*)&B[16], T1);                                                                */                                    
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[32], T2);                    /*    _mm_storeu_ps((float*)&B[32], T2);                                                                */                                    
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[48], T3);                    /*    _mm_storeu_ps((float*)&B[48], T3);                                                                */                                    
}                                                            /*  }                                                                                                   */
```

Comment: Awesome work! I like that you showed you need half the operations if you store two rows per register.  Does this mean with four rows per register e.g. with AVX2, you could do this in 6 operations?  It's good that you mentioned the bypass delays. I have a bad habit of avoiding mixing code which changes domains because I am afraid of the delays and I can never remember when the delays matter.  So anyway, first you expect 24 operations, then found 16 (which I found as well), and now you got it to 12.

Comment: My guess is that with AVX due to limitations of cross 128-bit lane operations that you won't be able to do this in 6 operations but in theory with a 256-bit / 32 byte two operand operations could do this in 6 operations I think.

Comment: Agree, I don't think that this is possible with 6 AVX2 "shuffle" (i.e. permute, unpack, etc.) instructions, but less then 12 should be possible. My first attempts didn't succeed however.

Comment: @wim: Was this compiled with -mavx or -msse4.2? I get a bit different assembly on loads and last unpacks with -msse4.2.https://godbolt.org/g/VAGXGD.

Comment: @xmas79 It was compiled with -mavx2 and -march=broadwell . Without AVX there are a few extra movdqa-s indeed because AVX instructions have 3 operands, while SSE have 2. With your code and with Z boson's code these extra movdqa-s are needed too.

Comment: @Zboson I transposed with 8 AVX2 instructions. I posted the code as an answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @wim If you found my comments confusing it's because I confused you with the OP.

Comment: If you compile with AVX then you should provide an AVX solution. The only good reason to use SSE with AVX is if you have SSE code already and don't want to put the effort to convert it to AVX or if you are using AMD hardware where AVX is really emulated as SSE twice anyway.

Comment: @Zboson : The OP asked for an SSE solution, not AVX. 
I think the compiled code with SSE and AVX compiler options is basicly
the same. The extra `movdqa`-s are 'free', because of the bottleneck on port 5.
On skylake it is better to compile SSE C-code to AVX128 than to SSE, 
to avoid [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake)
behaviour.

Comment: The SSE performance is worse on skylake due to library calls (such as printf) 
that might use AVX at runtime, without a proper vzeroupper.
With `gcc -O3  -m64 -msse3 -march=nehalem -falign-loops=16`, 1e9 transpositions take 4.7 sec. This reduces to
4.2 sec., if I insert `__asm__ __volatile__ ( "vzeroupper" : : : );` before the loop.
(Why is the SSE loop faster than the AVX loop???)

Comment: @wim did you try `-mvzeroupper`? BTW, the zeroupper issue (which is Microsoft's fault due to their silly 64-bit calling conventions) [manifests itself in very strange ways sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21965635/2542702).

Comment: I just meant that in your answer you show the vex encoded instructions. Only processors with AVX have that. So if you are going to use vex encoded instructions you might as well use AVX. If the OP wants the SSE solution then presumably he/she is interested in the result on hardware without AVX.

Comment: @Zboson : I tried `-mvzeroupper`, but it didn't help. The problem is that a `vzeroupper` is missing,
but with `-march=nehalem`, the compiler is not allowed to insert a vzeroupper`.
What do you mean with your remark about Microsoft? I am working on a Linux system.  I only showed the compiler output to illustrate that the casts do not generate instructions
,which is the same in the non VEX case.

Comment: I don't have a Nehalem or a Westmere cpu to work with. So the best thing I can do to give a
rough impression of the efficiency of the codes, is to compile with VEX encoded AVX128 instructions.
The idea is that if x is better than y with AVX128,
then x is also likely to be better with non-VEX encodings on an old cpu.
To make a fair comparison I compiled both your code and my code with the same compiler
options.

Comment: My Microsoft remark was referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819514/why-do-sse-instructions-preserve-the-upper-128-bit-of-the-ymm-registers/41824459#comment70882138_41824459).

Comment: I'm confused by the zeroupper thing now. The problem (at least before Skylake) was calling SSE code from AVX code. So if you compile with e.g. `mavx` and then call e.g. `sin` from the math library which was compiled with SSE you get a big delay. But you compiled with `nehalem` so everything should be in the SSE domain so not state change. This may have changed on Skylake. I cannot remember now, somebody answered a question on this recently.

Comment: Yeah, [it's different on Skylake](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41349852/2542702). That could explain a performance issue on Skylake even when you compile everything with SSE.

Answer (score 4):

Posting this as an answer. I'm also going to change the title of the question from "... with SSE" to "... with SIMD" due to some answers and comments received so far.

I succeeded in transposing the matrix with AVX2 in 8 instructions only, 10  including load/store (excluding masks loads). **EDIT: I found a shorter version. See below.** This is the case where the matrices are all contiguous in memory, so direct load/store can be used.

Here's the C code:

```
void tran8x8b_AVX2(char *src, char *dst) {
    __m256i perm = _mm256_set_epi8(
        0, 0, 0, 7,
        0, 0, 0, 5,
        0, 0, 0, 3,
        0, 0, 0, 1,

        0, 0, 0, 6,
        0, 0, 0, 4,
        0, 0, 0, 2,
        0, 0, 0, 0
    );

    __m256i tm = _mm256_set_epi8(
        15, 11, 7, 3,
        14, 10, 6, 2,
        13,  9, 5, 1,
        12,  8, 4, 0,

        15, 11, 7, 3,
        14, 10, 6, 2,
        13,  9, 5, 1,
        12,  8, 4, 0
    );

    __m256i load0 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&src[ 0]);
    __m256i load1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&src[32]);  

    __m256i perm0 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(load0, perm);   
    __m256i perm1 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(load1, perm);   

    __m256i transpose0 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(perm0, tm);    
    __m256i transpose1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(perm1, tm);    

    __m256i unpack0 = _mm256_unpacklo_epi32(transpose0, transpose1);    
    __m256i unpack1 = _mm256_unpackhi_epi32(transpose0, transpose1);

    perm0 = _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_permute2f128_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(unpack0), _mm256_castsi256_ps(unpack1), 32));    
    perm1 = _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_permute2f128_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(unpack0), _mm256_castsi256_ps(unpack1), 49));    

    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&dst[ 0], perm0);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&dst[32], perm1);
}
```

GCC was smart enough to perform a permutation during AVX load, saving two instructions. Here's the compiler output:

```
tran8x8b_AVX2(char*, char*):
        vmovdqa ymm1, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        vmovdqa ymm2, YMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        vpermd  ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        vpermd  ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+32]
        vpshufb ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        vpshufb ymm1, ymm1, ymm2
        vpunpckldq      ymm2, ymm0, ymm1
        vpunpckhdq      ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vinsertf128     ymm1, ymm2, xmm0, 1
        vperm2f128      ymm0, ymm2, ymm0, 49
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rsi], ymm1
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rsi+32], ymm0
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

It emitted the `vzerupper` instruction with -O3, but going down to -O1 removes this.

In case of my original problem (a large matrix and I'm zooming in to an 8x8 part of it), handling strides destroys the output in a pretty bad way:

```
void tran8x8b_AVX2(char *src, char *dst, int srcStride, int dstStride) {
    __m256i load0 = _mm256_set_epi64x(*(uint64_t*)(src + 3 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 2 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 1 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 0 * srcStride));
    __m256i load1 = _mm256_set_epi64x(*(uint64_t*)(src + 7 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 6 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 5 * srcStride), *(uint64_t*)(src + 4 * srcStride));

    // ... the same as before, however we can skip the final permutations because we need to handle the destination stride...

    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 0 * dstStride)) = _mm256_extract_epi64(unpack0, 0);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 1 * dstStride)) = _mm256_extract_epi64(unpack0, 1);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 2 * dstStride)) = _mm256_extract_epi64(unpack1, 0);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 3 * dstStride)) = _mm256_extract_epi64(unpack1, 1);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 4 * dstStride)) = _mm256_extract_epi64(unpack0, 2);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 5 * dstStride)) = _mm256_extract_epi64(unpack0, 3);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 6 * dstStride)) = _mm256_extract_epi64(unpack1, 2);
    *((uint64_t*)(dst + 7 * dstStride)) = _mm256_extract_epi64(unpack1, 3);
}
```

Here's the compiler output:

```
tran8x8b_AVX2(char*, char*, int, int):
        movsx   rdx, edx
        vmovq   xmm5, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        lea     r9, [rdi+rdx]
        vmovdqa ymm3, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movsx   rcx, ecx
        lea     r11, [r9+rdx]
        vpinsrq xmm0, xmm5, QWORD PTR [r9], 1
        lea     r10, [r11+rdx]
        vmovq   xmm4, QWORD PTR [r11]
        vpinsrq xmm1, xmm4, QWORD PTR [r10], 1
        lea     r8, [r10+rdx]
        lea     rax, [r8+rdx]
        vmovq   xmm7, QWORD PTR [r8]
        vmovq   xmm6, QWORD PTR [rax+rdx]
        vpinsrq xmm2, xmm7, QWORD PTR [rax], 1
        vinserti128     ymm1, ymm0, xmm1, 0x1
        vpinsrq xmm0, xmm6, QWORD PTR [rax+rdx*2], 1
        lea     rax, [rsi+rcx]
        vpermd  ymm1, ymm3, ymm1
        vinserti128     ymm0, ymm2, xmm0, 0x1
        vmovdqa ymm2, YMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        vpshufb ymm1, ymm1, ymm2
        vpermd  ymm0, ymm3, ymm0
        vpshufb ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        vpunpckldq      ymm2, ymm1, ymm0
        vpunpckhdq      ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vmovdqa xmm1, xmm2
        vmovq   QWORD PTR [rsi], xmm1
        vpextrq QWORD PTR [rax], xmm1, 1
        vmovdqa xmm1, xmm0
        add     rax, rcx
        vextracti128    xmm0, ymm0, 0x1
        vmovq   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm1
        add     rax, rcx
        vpextrq QWORD PTR [rax], xmm1, 1
        add     rax, rcx
        vextracti128    xmm1, ymm2, 0x1
        vmovq   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm1
        add     rax, rcx
        vpextrq QWORD PTR [rax], xmm1, 1
        vmovq   QWORD PTR [rax+rcx], xmm0
        vpextrq QWORD PTR [rax+rcx*2], xmm0, 1
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

However, this seems not a big deal if compared against the output my original code.

---

**EDIT: I found a shorter version. 4 instructions in total, 8 counting both load/stores.** This is possible because I read the matrix in a different way, hiding some "shuffles" in the "gather" instruction during load. Also, note that the final permutation is needed to perform the store because AVX2 doesn't have a "scatter" instruction. Having a scatter instruction would bring down everything to 2 instructions only. Also, note that I can handle without hassles the src stride by changing the content of the `vindex` vector.

Unfortunately this AVX_v2 seems to be slower than the previous one.  Here's the code:

```
void tran8x8b_AVX2_v2(char *src1, char *dst1) {
    __m256i tm = _mm256_set_epi8(
        15, 11, 7, 3,
        14, 10, 6, 2,
        13,  9, 5, 1,
        12,  8, 4, 0,

        15, 11, 7, 3,
        14, 10, 6, 2,
        13,  9, 5, 1,
        12,  8, 4, 0
    );

    __m256i vindex = _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56);
    __m256i perm = _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7);

     __m256i load0 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32((int*)src1, vindex, 1);
    __m256i load1 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32((int*)(src1 + 4), vindex, 1); 

    __m256i transpose0 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(load0, tm);    
    __m256i transpose1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(load1, tm);    

    __m256i final0 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(transpose0, perm);    
    __m256i final1 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(transpose1, perm);    

    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&dst1[ 0], final0);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&dst1[32], final1);
}
```

And here's the output of the compiler:

```
tran8x8b_AVX2_v2(char*, char*):
        vpcmpeqd        ymm3, ymm3, ymm3
        vmovdqa ymm2, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        vmovdqa ymm4, ymm3
        vpgatherdd      ymm0, DWORD PTR [rdi+4+ymm2*8], ymm3
        vpgatherdd      ymm1, DWORD PTR [rdi+ymm2*8], ymm4
        vmovdqa ymm2, YMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        vpshufb ymm1, ymm1, ymm2
        vpshufb ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        vmovdqa ymm2, YMMWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        vpermd  ymm1, ymm2, ymm1
        vpermd  ymm0, ymm2, ymm0
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rsi], ymm1
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rsi+32], ymm0
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

Comment: Don't worry about `vzeroupper`. That's only emitted for the function with external linkage. If you call your function within the same source file your compiler will likely inline in which case it will not generate `vzeroupper`.  I would do `static void tran8x8b_AVX2`.

Comment: We have concentrated on number of instructions but another important thing to consider is port pressure. If I recall the permutes and shuffles all go to one port whereas blends go to two ports. In some cases it actually makes sense to use more instructions if this can reduce port pressure. E.g. [in some cases two shuffles can be replaced by one shuffle and two blends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25627536/2542702).

Comment: @Zboson: Indeed. I just benchmarked the 8 instr function, it's just a bit faster (6.2s) than my 16 instr (6.4s), but slower than wim's version (5.3s).

Comment: Memory bandwidth may be the main bottleneck anyway.  What is your hardware exactly?  When benchmarking it's important to state the hardware (CPU), OS, and compiler, and compiler options. I don't understand why your AVX version would be slower than the SSE (with vex encoding) version. Those results could be within the uncertainty. You have to run many times and take an average or median. Also you have to "warm up" the cache so if you run one test cold the next test runs hot and this could bias the result. Your probably know all this already.

Comment: Run these tests on another machine: OSX, compiled with `LLVM version 8.0.0` with `-O3 -mavx2 -march=native`. CPU is I7-4750HQ, RAM is DDR3 1600MHz. I ran these tests multiple times and results seems consistent: my code: `5.3s`, wim's code: `3.9s`, AVX2 code: `6.4s`.  I currently don't have access to other hardware to run other tests. I'd be glad if someone else could benchmark on other hardware to see how it performs.

Comment: With respect to the register to register transpose your AVX2 transpose is great. It's 8 
(port 5) shuffles instead of 12, Therefore the throughput might be up to a factor 1.5 better than 
my solution. For the latency I wouldn't expect much difference due to slow cross lane
shuffles (3c latency instead of 1c for normal shuffles).
Note that my test-loop is a simple latency test, while in your application you might 
be more interested in the throughput!

Comment: Indeed bandwidth might be the bottleneck if your data is not in cache. Otherwise port 5 (p5) pressure
is a point of concern. Your AVX2 code has 18 instructions on p5: vpinsrq vinserti128 vpermd 
vpshufb vpunpckldq vpunpckhdq vpextrq vextracti128, if I counted right.
With my SSE code I would use `_mm_loadl_pi`, `_mm_loadh_pi`, `_mm_storel_pi` and `_mm_storeh_pi` 
to read and write with general strides. Only the `_mm_loadh_pi` uses p5. This leads to
a total of 16 p5 instructions. Try to avoid `_mm256_extract_epi64`, it is not a single cpu instructon.
What about `_mm256_maskstore_epi64` ?

Comment: @wim, interesting point about cross lane shuffles? Are these multi micro-op instructions? In that case they are probably implemented similar to how they would have to be done with AVX but with microcode which would mean they are only marginally better than doing the cross late shuffles with AVX.

Comment: @wim, so I looked into the `vpermpd` it's just one micro-op so likely not microcode. It just happens to have a bit high latency. It's not like `dpps` which uses four micro-ops (latency 14) and is clearly microcode.

Comment: @wim I had a look, but it has a throughput of 2, meaning it would "block" the write port to 2 cycles. I supposed it could be slower. Probably a copy to a local memory and then a plain 8*8 bytes copy is faster? In the meantime I updated the post, I found a shorter version.

Comment: @Zboson I updated the post because I found a shorter (but slower) version.

Comment: @xmas79. Cool. But gather is slow. You can transpose a 16x16 int32 matrix with AVX512 in only 16 gathers and it's still slower than 64 shuffles/permutes. I guess your case with stride may be a good case for using gather/scatter. What is your hardware? Gather was slow on Haswell, improved on Broadwell, even better on Skylake. Despite that I still don't know if their is a case where it's ever better performance wise to use. But I have never really profiled it except on Knights Landing so it would be interesting to test your case on Skylake (which does not have scatter though).

Comment: @Zboson I'm on Haswell. I modified wim's code to handle the src/dst strides, and compared with my AVX_v2. It still wins `7.3s` vs `10.0s`, so `gather` is really slow. Probably there's no "space" for an 8x8 bytes matrix transpose with AVX. So far wim's code is the fastest I've found.

Comment: @Zboson : Indeed it was possible to reduce the number of 'shuffles' by modifying the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42222490/2439725) with blends. On Skylake the new code is faster than the old one.

Comment: @wim Awesome! It's great to see so many people improving on this. How does your new code compare to [this new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42316675/2542702)? Sadly, my answer is the worst now. But if I had not answered would this question of generated so much interest?

Comment: @Zboson : In my simple test [that code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42316675/2439725) runs in 3.9 sec, which 
is faster than my original answer.
It has 12 'shuffles' too, but somehow it is a bit faster. Maybe due to the first shuffles which only depend on a single load, 
while in my case the shufps needs two loads that are finished.
My updated answer is likely to be the fastest (at least for now..).

Comment: @wim, I missed that it has 12 shuffles, the OP packed 4 shuffles in the stores. I had not given it much thought.

Comment: @Zboson : Yes, it's 12 shuffles. The latency is better, but I have not tested the throughput (yet). Throughput might be more relevant for xmas79 than latency. Maybe I will do some throughput experiments later on.

Comment: @wim: I failed to see how powturbo's answer beats yours. I guessed it removes some instruction dependencies too. Now it would be interesting to know how powturbo benchmarked all the methods and if it could test your further improvements also....

Comment: @Zboson: Well I could post another 16x16 bytes matrix transpose question then :)

Comment: @xmas79 : I am not sure if powturbo uses a suitable benchmark. Maybe his benchmark transposes a huge matrix that does not fit into any cache. To assess the 8x8 byte transpose performance it is better to access only L1 cache. In that case the performance should be much better than 1.5 cycle  per byte, which powturbo reports. In my experiments the performance of `tran8x8b_SSE_v2` is about 0.25 cycle per byte. Note that your matrix fits in L1 cache. Do you have time to test how well my new code performs within your application?

Comment: @xmas79 I think it would have been better if you had asked for an AVX2-256 answer as well. People got too hung up on 128-bit operations. Why were you primarily interested in 128-bit operations (especially since you have Haswell)? Personally I think we should be thinking about how to exploit 256-bit operations more and move on from 128-bit operations.

Comment: @wim: sorry for being late on this. I tested the functions within a context of semi-real data. The performances are practically the same. Indeed the application flow currently includes an heavy computation stage after the transpose, and it makes the cost of the transpose pretty negligible, probably due to the fact that my matrices are usually small.

Comment: @Zboson I was thinking about some form of compatibility with older processors. However it probably makes no more sense.

Answer (score 3):

A simplified one

```
void tp128_8x8(char *A, char *B) {
  __m128i sv = _mm_set_epi8(15, 7, 14, 6, 13, 5, 12, 4, 11, 3, 10, 2, 9, 1, 8,  0);
  __m128i iv[4], ov[4];

  ov[0] = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)A), sv);
  ov[1] = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(A+16)), sv);
  ov[2] = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(A+32)), sv);
  ov[3] = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(A+48)), sv);

  iv[0] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(ov[0], ov[1]); 
  iv[1] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(ov[0], ov[1]); 
  iv[2] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(ov[2], ov[3]); 
  iv[3] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(ov[2], ov[3]); 

  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)B,      _mm_unpacklo_epi32(iv[0], iv[2]));
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(B+16), _mm_unpackhi_epi32(iv[0], iv[2]));
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(B+32), _mm_unpacklo_epi32(iv[1], iv[3]));
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(B+48), _mm_unpackhi_epi32(iv[1], iv[3]));
}



Benchmark:i5-5300U 2.3GHz (cycles per byte)
tran8x8b           : 2.140
tran8x8b_SSE       : 1.602
tran8x8b_SSE_v2    : 1.551
tp128_8x8          : 1.535
tran8x8b_AVX2      : 1.563
tran8x8b_AVX2_v2   : 1.731
```

Comment: Could this just be some noise? Or this code removes some instruction dependencies that is present in other code?

Answer (score 2):

Normally when load and store instructions are not counted it's because the code is working with a matrix in register e.g. doing multiple operations in addition to the transpose in a loop. The loads and stores in this case are not counted because they are not part of the main loop.

But in your code the loads and stores (or rather sets and extracts) are doing part of the transpose.

GCC implements `_mm_set_epi64x` for SSE4.1 in your code with `_mm_insert_epi64` and `_mm_loadl_epi64`. The insert instruction is doing part of the transpose i.e. the transpose starts at `load0,1,2,3` not at `shuffle0,1,2,3`. And then your final `store0,1,2,3` values don't contain the transpose either. You have to use eight `_mm_extract_epi64` instructions to finish the transpose in memory.  So it does not really make sense to not count the set and extract intrinsics.

In any case, it turns out you can do the transpose from register with only 16 instructions using only SSSE3 like this:

```
//__m128i B0, __m128i B1, __m128i B2, __m128i B3
__m128i mask = _mm_setr_epi8(0x0,0x04,0x01,0x05, 0x02,0x06,0x03,0x07, 0x08,0x0c,0x09,0x0d, 0x0a,0x0e,0x0b,0x0f);

__m128i T0, T1, T2, T3;
T0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(B0,B1);
T1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(B0,B1);
T2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(B2,B3);
T3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(B2,B3);

B0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(T0,T2);
B1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(T0,T2);
B2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(T1,T3);
B3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(T1,T3);

T0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(B0,B2);
T1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(B0,B2);
T2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(B1,B3);
T3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(B1,B3);

B0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T0,mask);
B1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T1,mask);
B2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T2,mask);
B3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T3,mask);
```

I'm not sure if it makes sense to exclude the loads and store here either because I'm not sure how convenient it is to work with a 8x8 byte matrix in four 128-bit registers.

Here is code testing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

void print8x8b(char *A) {
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++) {
      printf("%2d ", A[i*8+j]);
    } puts("");
  } puts("");
}

void tran8x8b(char *A, char *B) {
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++) {
      B[j*8+i] = A[i*8+j];
    }
  }
}

void tran8x8b_SSE(char *A, char *B) {
  __m128i mask = _mm_setr_epi8(0x0,0x04,0x01,0x05, 0x02,0x06,0x03,0x07, 0x08,0x0c,0x09,0x0d, 0x0a,0x0e,0x0b,0x0f);

  __m128i B0, B1, B2, B3, T0, T1, T2, T3;
  B0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[ 0]);
  B1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[16]);
  B2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[32]);
  B3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&A[48]);

  T0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(B0,B1);
  T1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(B0,B1);
  T2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(B2,B3);
  T3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(B2,B3);

  B0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(T0,T2);
  B1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(T0,T2);
  B2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(T1,T3);
  B3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(T1,T3);

  T0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(B0,B2);
  T1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(B0,B2);
  T2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(B1,B3);
  T3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(B1,B3);

  B0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T0,mask);
  B1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T1,mask);
  B2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T2,mask);
  B3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(T3,mask);

  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[ 0], B0);
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[16], B1);
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[32], B2);
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&B[48], B3);
}

int main(void) {
  char A[64], B[64], C[64];
  for(int i=0; i<64; i++) A[i] = i;
  print8x8b(A);
  tran8x8b(A,B);
  print8x8b(B);
  tran8x8b_SSE(A,C);
  print8x8b(C);
}
```

Comment: I see. My code "degenerates" into something similar when used with an 8x8 matrix (eg `A[64]`). However, my code can handle bigger matrices as well, where rows are not at multiple of 8 bytes (eg `A[32 * 32]`) and you cannot use `_mm_load`. How'd you handle such cases? (+1 BTW)

Comment: @xmas79, oh I see what you mean, I did not give enough thought to why you were interested in the stride. In that case using insert and extract make sense. In any case, this reinforces why it makes no sense to not count the loads and stores. But in any case, then the problem is that the links you pointed to do not discuss a 8x8 byte transpose but a 8x8 short transpose (and a 4x4 char transpose) so your assumption that 24 operations was necessary was wrong. Only 16 operations are necessary. We both showed with different methods.

Comment: @xmas79, maybe my assumption was wrong that `store0,1,2,3` does not contain the transpose. You only use extract to handle the stride. I get it now. My answer is not totally correct then. The problem again was your assumption that 24 operations are necessary, it's only 16.

Answer (score 2):

This was really interesting to me, and I was looking to do exactly this, but for various reasons, I ended up needing to do it in Go, instead of C, and I didn't have vector intrinsics, so I thought "well, I'll just write something and see how it does".

My reported times, on a ~3.6GHz CPU, are about 28ns per 64-byte block transposed for a naive implementation, and about 19ns each for one done using bit shifts. I used perf to confirm the numbers, which seemed a bit unlikely to me, and they seem to add up. The fancy bit shift implementation is a bit over 250 instructions, and gets about 3.6 instructions per cycle, so it comes out to about 69-70 cycles per operation.

This is Go, but honestly it should be trivial to implement; it's just treating the input array of 64 bytes as 8 uint64_t.

You can get another nanosecond or so with declaring some of these things as new variables to hint to the register allocator.

```
import (
"unsafe"
)

const (
    hi16 = uint64(0xFFFF0000FFFF0000)
    lo16 = uint64(0x0000FFFF0000FFFF)
    hi8  = uint64(0xFF00FF00FF00FF00)
    lo8  = uint64(0x00FF00FF00FF00FF)
)

// Okay, this might take some explaining. We are working on a logical
// 8x8 matrix of bytes, which we get as a 64-byte array. We want to transpose
// it (row/column).
//
// start:
// [[00 08 16 24 32 40 48 56]
//  [01 09 17 25 33 41 49 57]
//  [02 10 18 26 34 42 50 58]
//  [03 11 19 27 35 43 51 59]
//  [04 12 20 28 36 44 52 60]
//  [05 13 21 29 37 45 53 61]
//  [06 14 22 30 38 46 54 62]
//  [07 15 23 31 39 47 55 63]]
//
// First, let's make sure everything under 32 is in the top four rows,
// and everything over 32 is in the bottom four rows. We do this by
// swapping pairs of 32-bit words.
// swap32:
// [[00 08 16 24 04 12 20 28]
//  [01 09 17 25 05 13 21 29]
//  [02 10 18 26 06 14 22 30]
//  [03 11 19 27 07 15 23 31]
//  [32 40 48 56 36 44 52 60]
//  [33 41 49 57 37 45 53 61]
//  [34 42 50 58 38 46 54 62]
//  [35 43 51 59 39 47 55 63]]
//
// Next, let's make sure everything over 16 or 48 is in the bottom two
// rows of the two four-row sections, and everything under 16 or 48 is
// in the top two rows of the section. We do this by swapping masked
// pairs in much the same way:
// swap16:
// [[00 08 02 10 04 12 06 14]
//  [01 09 03 11 05 13 07 15]
//  [16 24 18 26 20 28 22 30]
//  [17 25 19 27 21 29 23 31]
//  [32 40 34 42 36 44 38 46]
//  [33 41 35 43 37 45 39 47]
//  [48 56 50 58 52 60 54 62]
//  [49 57 51 59 53 61 55 63]]
//
// Now, we will do the same thing to each pair -- but because of
// clever choices in the specific arrange ment leading up to this, that's
// just one more byte swap, where each 2x2 block has its upper right
// and lower left corners swapped, and that turns out to be an easy
// shift and mask.
func UnswizzleLazy(m *[64]uint8) {
    // m32 treats the 8x8 array as a 2x8 array, because
    // it turns out we only need to swap a handful of the
    // bits...
    m32 := (*[16]uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(&m[0]))
    m32[1], m32[8] = m32[8], m32[1]
    m32[3], m32[10] = m32[10], m32[3]
    m32[5], m32[12] = m32[12], m32[5]
    m32[7], m32[14] = m32[14], m32[7]
    m64 := (*[8]uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&m[0]))
    // we're now at the state described above as "swap32"
    tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 :=
        (m64[0]&lo16)|(m64[2]&lo16)<<16,
        (m64[1]&lo16)|(m64[3]&lo16)<<16,
        (m64[0]&hi16)>>16|(m64[2]&hi16),
        (m64[1]&hi16)>>16|(m64[3]&hi16)
    tmp4, tmp5, tmp6, tmp7 :=
        (m64[4]&lo16)|(m64[6]&lo16)<<16,
        (m64[5]&lo16)|(m64[7]&lo16)<<16,
        (m64[4]&hi16)>>16|(m64[6]&hi16),
        (m64[5]&hi16)>>16|(m64[7]&hi16)
    // now we're at "swap16".
    lo8 := lo8
    hi8 := hi8
    m64[0], m64[1] = (tmp0&lo8)|(tmp1&lo8)<<8, (tmp0&hi8)>>8|tmp1&hi8
    m64[2], m64[3] = (tmp2&lo8)|(tmp3&lo8)<<8, (tmp2&hi8)>>8|tmp3&hi8
    m64[4], m64[5] = (tmp4&lo8)|(tmp5&lo8)<<8, (tmp4&hi8)>>8|tmp5&hi8
    m64[6], m64[7] = (tmp6&lo8)|(tmp7&lo8)<<8, (tmp6&hi8)>>8|tmp7&hi8
}
```

What this is doing is, I hope, reasonably obvious: shuffle the half-words around, so the first four words have all the values that belong in them, and the last four have all the values that belong in them. Then do a similar thing to each set of four words, so you end up with the things that belong in the top two words in the top two, etcetera.

I wasn't going to comment until I realized that, if the cycles/byte numbers above are right, this actually outperforms the shuffle/unpack solution.

(Note that this is an in-place transpose, but it's easy to use temps for the intermediate steps and do the final store somewhere else. It's actually probably faster.)

UPDATE: I originally described my algorithm slightly incorrectly, then I realized that I could actually do what I'd described. This one's running about 65.7 cycles per 64 bits.

EDIT #2: Tried one of the above AVX versions on this machine. On my hardware (Xeon E3-1505M, nominally 3GHz), I get a little over 10 cycles per 64-byte block, so, about 6 bytes per cycle. That seems a lot more reasonable to me than 1.5 cycles per byte did.

EDIT #3: Got down a bit further, about 45 cycles per 64 bits, by just writing the first part as shifts and masks on uint64 instead of trying to be "smart" and just move the 32 bits I cared about.

Comment: For best throughput on your Sandybridge(?) CPU, you probably need to adapt wim's AVX2 `_mm_blend_epi32` to use AVX1 `_mm_blend_ps`.  Or actually not, because Sandybridge has 2/clock integer shuffle throughput, unlike Haswell and later with AVX2.  So the 12 integer shuffle version should be great.  On SnB, FP shuffles have 1/clock throughput because 256-bit versions of them exist, and they only widened the shuffle unit that supports those shuffles, or something.

Comment: I'm curious what asm this compiles to.  But I don't really know Go, so copy/pasting this into https://godbolt.org/z/sF0p23 didn't work: GCCGo chokes on the `unsafe` keyword.

Comment: i'm fine with not having best throughput, i just wanted to see whether i could make it "fast enough" without having to do assembly. this should be directly translateable to naive C, just type-punning the incoming array of 64 bytes to an array of uint64_t, and then it's all shift ops and the like. You can get it to compile on godbolt.org if you add the missing `import ("unsafe")` that i forgot to include in it (which i'm now adding).

Comment: Changing the shift to `c = b ^ (a>>16)) & 0x0000ffff0000ffffull; a,c = a ^ (c <<16), b^c;`, the number of instructions in the kernel comes down to 48 (in arm64).

Answer (score 1):

#### AVX512VBMI ([Cascade Lake / Ice Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512))

AVX512VBMI introduces [`vpermb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermb), a 64-byte lane-crossing shuffle with byte granularity.
`_mm512_permutexvar_epi8( __m512i idx, __m512i a);`

Existing CPUs that support it run it as a single uop, with 1/clock throughput.  (https://www.uops.info/html-tp/CNL/VPERMB_ZMM_ZMM_M512-Measurements.html)

**That trivializes the problem, making it possible with 1 instruction (at least for the stride=8 case where the whole 8x8 block is contiguous)**.  Otherwise you should look at `vpermt2b` to shuffle together bytes from 2 sources.  But that's 3 uops on CannonLake.

```
// TODO: strided loads / stores somehow for stride != 8
// AVX512VBMI
void TransposeBlock8x8_contiguous(uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dst)
{
    const __m512i trans8x8shuf = _mm512_set_epi8(
        63, 63-8*1, 63-8*2, 63-8*3, 63-8*4, ...
        ...
        57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9, 1,
        56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0
   );

    __m512i vsrc = _mm512_loadu_si512(src);
    __m512i shuffled = _mm512_permutexvar_epi8(trans8x8shuf, vsrc);
    _mm512_storeu_si512(dst, shuffled);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/wrfyy3

Apparently `_mm512_setr_epi8` doesn't exist for gcc/clang (only the 256 and 128 versions) so you have to define the constant in last-to-first order, opposite of C array initializer order.

---

`vpermb` even works with the data as a memory source operand, so it can load+shuffle in a single instruction.  But according to https://uops.info/, it doesn't micro-fuse on CannonLake: unlike [`vpermd zmm, zmm, [r14]`](https://www.uops.info/html-tp/CNL/VPERMD_ZMM_ZMM_M512-Measurements.html) which decodes to 1 fused-domain uop (note "retire_slots: 1.0")
[`vpermd zmm, zmm, [r14]`](https://www.uops.info/html-tp/CNL/VPERMB_ZMM_ZMM_M512-Measurements.html) decodes to 2 separate uops for the front-end / fused-domain: "retire_slots: 2.0").  This from experimental testing with perf counters on a real CannonLake CPU.  uops.info doesn't have a Cascade Lake or Ice Lake available yet, so it's possible it will be even more efficient there.

The uops.info tables uselessly count total number of unfused-domain uops, so you have to click on an instruction to see if it micro-fuses or not.

---

#### Source or dst strided, not contiguous, data

I guess you'd want to do qword (8-byte) loads into XMM registers and shuffle together pairs of inputs, or concatenate them with `movhps` or `pinsrq`.  It's possibly worth it to use a qword-gather load with strided indices, but that's often not worth it.

I'm not sure if it's worth combining as far as YMM registers, let alone ZMM, or if it's best to only get as wide as XMM registers so we can efficiently scatter qwords back to memory manually with `vmovq` and `vmovhps` (which don't need a shuffle uop, just a store, on Intel CPUs).  If the dst is contiguous, merging a non-contiguous strided src makes a lot more sense.

AVX512VBMI `vpermt2b ymm` looks like it would be useful for shuffle+merge like a lane-crossing `punpcklbw`, selecting any 32 bytes from the concatenation of two other 32-byte YMM registers.  (Or 64 from 2x 64-byte regs for the ZMM version).  But unfortunately on CannonLake it costs 3 uops, like `vpermt2w` on Skylake-X and Cannon Lake.

If we can worry about bytes later, `vpermt2d` is efficient on CPUs that support it (single uop)!  Skylake-X and later.

Ice Lake has one per 2-cycle throughput for `vpermt2b` ([instlat](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00706E5_IceLakeY_InstLatX64.txt)), perhaps because it has an extra shuffle unit that can run some (but not all) shuffle uops.  Notice for example that `vpshufb xmm` and `ymm` is 0.5c throughput, but `vpshufb zmm` is 1c throughput.  But `vpermb` is always just 1c throughput.

I wonder if we can take advantage of merge-masking?  Like maybe `vpmovzxbq` to zero-extend input bytes to qwords.  (one 8-byte row -> 64-byte ZMM register).  Then maybe dword left-shift with merge-masking into another register?  No, that doesn't help, the useful data is in the same dword elements for both inputs unless you do something to one register first, defeating the purpose.

---

**Overlapped byte-masked stores** (`vmovdqu8 [rdi + 0..7]{k1}, zmm0..7`) of `vpmovzxbq` load results are also possible, but probably not efficient.  All but one of them would be misaligned, at best.  The store buffer and/or cache hardware might be able to efficiently commit 8x masked stores, though.

A hybrid strategy doing some moving around in registers and some masked-stores might be interesting to balance shuffle/blend vs. store work for a contiguous `dst`.  Especially if all the stores can be aligned, which would require moving data around in each vector so it's in the right place.

Ice Lake has 2 store execution units.  (IDK if L1d cache commit can keep up with that, or if merging in the store buffer usually helps, or if that just helps with bursts of work.)

Answer (score 1):

Most answers here use a combination of different sized shuffles and permutations using `_mm_shuffle_epi8`, which is available only at SSSE3 and above.

A pure SSE2 implementation with 12* instruction kernel can be formed from interleaving the first 32 elements with the last 32 elements three times in a row:

```
void systolic_kernel(__m128i a[4]) {
    __m128i a0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(a[0], a[2]);
    __m128i a1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(a[0], a[2]);
    __m128i a2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(a[1], a[3]);
    __m128i a3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(a[1], a[3]);
    a[0] = a0;
    a[1] = a1;
    a[2] = a2;
    a[3] = a3;
}

void transpose(__m128i a[4]) {
    systolic_kernel(a);
    systolic_kernel(a);
    systolic_kernel(a);
}
```

*without VEX encoding (for three operand instructions), there will be 6 potentially zero cost `movdqa` instructions added.

The same strategy can be more easily applied to 4x4, 16x16 transposes and more, as the calculation of the indices to be permuted and the block sizes is factored out from the equation.

Comment: `movdqa` is never zero *cost*, only zero *latency*. ([Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342)).  Often front-end throughput and/or ROB capacity to "see" the next independent work for out-of-order exec are relevant.  And I-cache / uop-cache footprint aren't free either, in larger programs.